# C# Source Generators debug in vscode

Tags: c#, unix, visual-studio-code, msbuild, roslyn

How can I debug the `ISourceGenerator` code during the build process with vscode? Examples on the net use `Debugger.Launch()` but this only works in Visual Studio.

```
    [Generator]
    public class HelloWorldGenerator : ISourceGenerator
    {
        public void Execute(GeneratorExecutionContext context)
        {
      
        }

        public void Initialize(GeneratorInitializationContext context)
        {
            if (!Debugger.IsAttached)
            {
                // how to make it break here?
                Debugger.Launch();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It doesn't answer your question, but you can debug generator in controlled environment with tests [cookbook](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/docs/features/source-generators.cookbook.md#unit-testing-of-generators)

Comment: `Debugger.Launch()` isn't Visual Studio-specific; it will offer whichever debuggers are registered, so I assume VS Code isn't registering one.  I don't use VS Code much, but [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_debugger-extensions) might help.

Comment: @sellotape the problem is that `vsdbg` is not running during the build process with vscode. It can debug fine at application runtime.

Answer (score 5):

If you add such construction:

```cs
while (!System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
```

you will be able to stop build process until you attach any debugger you want. I use Rider IDE, but this should work for VS Code too. When it stucks in cycle, it is available for attaching as .NET Core process:
[image: .NET Core process]

Comment: seems to be the most reasonable solution i found. Thanks!